# React input losing focus when context state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a global context that store my access token and my refresh token, I am trying to create an background loop that will refresh the token every few minutes. However I noticed that any time you are typing in a input field and the tokens are updated. The input field will lose focus, this is obviously extremely annoying. Is there anyway to mitigate this? If not, is there some other way to store my tokens so that they can be updated in the background?

Comment: Please provide your code related to input field. I'd think you need to use `input` field with `useRef` in uncontrolled mode.

Comment: This shouldn't generally happen because React works off a virtual DOM, and won't recreate elements needlessly: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-darwin-5bmumn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js
Post a codesandbox

Comment: You are probsbly triggering an unnecessary rerender when you get the new tokens. Are you saving the tokens at state maybe?